# Copying folder and contents using python

Tags: python

I am trying to work out how to copy folders and contents from one drive to another using python, with the use of user input for determining which drives to copy to and from?

From what i have looked at shutil.copytree is what i need to use to but i am struggling with how to link it in with user input?

Answer (score 2):

**shutil** has many methods you can use. One of which is:

```
from shutil import copyfile

copyfile(src, dst)
```

Documentation: https://docs.python.org/2/library/shutil.html